# Steps to upgrade GWT from 2.0 to 2.7

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, gwt-2.7

I have to support IE11 in my application. So, i have to upgrade GWT in my application from 2.0 to 2.7. I tried to search for GWT migration document but couldn't get any. Is there any step by step guide available that we can follow for GWT upgrade ? Please help if anyone has experience in upgrading GWT to 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

GWT doesn't have an installer. If you are already running a prior version just download the latest version of GWT here:

htttp://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html

Change your libraries to point to your gwt-2.7.0 folder rather than 2.0. If you are using an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse you can simply delete the old plugins and install the new ones.

If you created your application using the command prompt, you can simply open up the command prompt and change your directory to the gwt-2.7.0 folder using:

```
    cd C:\Users\yourname\gwt-2.7.0
```

After doing so run the command:

```
    ./webAppCreator -out YourAppName com.mycompany.mywebapp.YourAppName
```

Inside your gwt-2.7.0 folder there should be a new folder named "YourAppName." Place all of your source code, html, css documents, and other files from your 2.0 application in their appropriate places.